# FQL how to get the insights for a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=140902935963424 AND metric='page_fan_adds' AND end_time=1334905200 AND period=86400
```

HI  I have wrote a query to get the fan_page_adds insights but the query did not get executed. I cannot see any wrong with it and i used the facebook page id as the object id. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried this on the facebook developer site?https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer switch to the fql tab and try your query. It could be down to encoding on your site or permissions

Comment: Same with Graph API requests for page insights using page access token. Might be a bug on Facebook side: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/474441152566158?browse=search_50225a30018c91731625449 Check out other bugs as well in [fb's bug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs?search_view=search&search_ids[0]=156654881077642&&search_statuses[0]=open).